# MPI_Gather using custom MPI_Datatype

Tags: c++, mpi

I know similar questions of this sort have been asked on here before but I can't seem to find any matching my particular problem.

I have 4 std::vectors that have the same length on a given node, but length may differ across nodes. They are of type int, int, double, int. I want them to be gathered by the root node in a single MPI call hence I have resorted to using the MPI_Datatype:

```
// #1 Create an array on the root node containing the sizes of the vectors on each node
int nodevecsizes[commsize] = {0};
int localvecsize = intvec1.size();
MPI_Gather(&localvecsize,1,MPI_INT,nodevecsizes,1,MPI_INT,0,comm);

// #2 Create MPI struct to merge our 4 vectors on each node
int nitems = 4;
int blocklengths[nitems]        = {vecsize};
MPI_Datatype types[nitems]      = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT};
MPI_Aint vectorPointers[nitems] = {&intvec1, &intvec2, &doublevec, &intvec3};
MPI_Datatype nodeData;
MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems, blocklengths,vectorPointers,types, &nodeData);
MPI_Type_commit(&nodeData);
```

My end goal is to have 4 vectors of type int, int, double, int on the root node containing the merged vectors from all nodes.

The issue i'm having is that I'm not sure how to make the MPI_Gatherv/MPI_Gather call in this scenario as the nodeData struct is defined to have a fixed length. Am I approaching this correct way and how do I go about trying to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this in a single call because you have 3 vectors of `MPI_INT` and one vector of `MPI_DOUBLE`. You can gather the 3 vectors of `MPI_INT` in one shot but it gets tricky. Your datatype would contains one element of each vector, and resized to 4, and you would then use `MPI_Gatherv()` with `MPI_Bottom` so you do not need to calculate displacements when building your derived datatype. Unless your arrays are very small, I am not even sure that would be faster than using `MPI_Gatherv()` 3 times.

Comment: @Gilles He can put all the integers into all doubles and then send/receive all doubles in one shot. That works as long as he knows how to split them up again into integers and doubles on the root node.

Comment: Does this work with (collective) `MPI_Gatherv()`?

Comment: Also, the purpose of using derived datatype is to avoid manual pack/unpack (if this is what you meant by “putting all the integer into all doubles”)

Comment: That seems unnecessary complex and most likely not possible without some arcane use of resized MPI datatypes that will render the code completely unreadable. If the vectors aren't very short, simply make four `MPI_Gatherv` calls or make four `MPI_Igatherv` calls and complete them at once. Otherwise, turn the four vectors into a single vector of structs with four fields on the sender side and then do the opposite on the receiver side.